# Why is the signal for the QCheckBox not emitted?

Tags: c++, qt4

I am trying to insert in my UI a check box which can set a boolean variable from another class true or false according to its checked status. The problem is that the signal is not emitted.

The variable is defined in the header file of my 1st class (renderarea.h) as

```
public:
bool selectionMode;
```

The slot is defined in the 2nd class' header file as void

```
protected slots:
void setSelectionMode(bool mode);
```

And the signal is connected to the slot in my 2nd class source file in the constructor as:

```
PaintWidget::PaintWidget(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::PaintWidget)
{
connect(ui->selectionModeCheckBox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(setSelectionMode(bool)));
}
void PaintWidget::setSelectionMode(bool mode)
{
    ui->displayWidget->selectionMode = mode;

    QMessageBox msgbox;
    if (ui->displayWidget->selectionMode == true)
        msgbox.setText("selection mode is true");
    else
        msgbox.setText("selection mode is false");
}
```

I am using the QMessageBox here only for testing reasons. But when debugging I saw that the signal is not emitted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One quick question, could you make your connection invalid, and check that in the debug output you get the right error message (something like qt::connect impossible to connect)

Comment: i don't get any error messages. that is why i am asking here. i don't understand why the signal is not emitting.

Comment: In your ParentWidget class, do you have the Q_OBJECT macro?  That can cause some oddities with connection problems.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to make sure a number of things are in place:

1. `setupUi`
2. `connect` succeeded
3. checkbox value really changed

First, I don't see where you called `setupUi`. You'll want to do this in the constructor:

```
PaintWidget::PaintWidget(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::PaintWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->selectionModeCheckBox,
        SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(setSelectionMode(bool)));
}
```

Second, make sure that the return value of [connect](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qobject.html#connect-2) indicates it succeeded.

Third, I presume you're manually clicking the checkbox, but for sake of testing you could do that after the connect in your constructor:

```
ui->selectionModeCheckBox->setChecked(true);
```

Comment: The setupUi is in my code. I just forgot it above. I set the box as checked after the connect in my constructor and when the application opened it was checked. and in the debugger for connect it only says <invalid> and <unknown>. when i manually click the box on my Ui while debugging it doesn't do anything; it doesn't go to connect.

Comment: The debugger won't go to `connect`. All connect does is establish a connection between a sender and receiver. Does `connect` succeed? If you add `CONFIG += debug` you should be able to step into most everything and see the event emitted.

Comment: yes. it succeeds. i found the error. the exec function for the message box was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, when you say the slot is in the header file, you do mean after the slots: label, right?

Comment: yes. it is defined as protected slot: void setSelectionMode(bool mode);

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible that the wrong element was mistakenly named setSelectionModeCheckBox in the ui designer? It's hard to guess without knowing a bit more about the application.

Comment: it is an application where i draw. and I wanted this check box so that I can switch between drawing modes (if it is checked draw x if not draw y). that is the basic idea. i have only 1 check box in the application so I doubt there was some mistake with the name. I tried the debugger but the only time my application is accessing the connect statement is when it starts. after that no matter how many times i check and un-check the box it is not going in the connect mode. i also tried all the other signals (clicked, statechanged) but nothing seems to be working. and i really don't know why.

Comment: i updated my question, although there is not that much difference. the only code related to the check box is above. do you want to see something specific?

Comment: Thanks, it's easier to puzzle about these things with eyes on code.

Comment: i am doing everything in Qt Creator. i don't manually use qmake.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use the [stateChanged()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcheckbox.html#stateChanged) signal, emitted by the checkbox when its status changes. It gives you an integer, because checkboxes can also be tristate (but you can just use that int value as a boolean, in your case).

Answer (score 0):

well,I often use the checkbox in the Dialog(settingDialog, selectionDialog,etc), so signal-slot is not need in this situation,just check the checkbox state when the "OK" button is clicked, and deal with it in the accept function.In your situation, I don't think checkbox is a good choice.